# Cmd like Terminal with Rich package support

Tags: python

I recently found 'Rich' python package. In pypi I saw an sample image which impressed me. Is there a cmd like terminal similar to it.

It should have:

- The same good color transition support.
- Custom font support
- Windows 7 compatible
- Similar to the normal cmd (which I cn use instead of cmd.exe)
- Available for somewhat slow computer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly; if you are asking: 'what are good and nice terminal emulators on Windows with package support' I am suggesting to take a look at [hyper](https://hyper.is/), which is a terminal based on [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org).

> The goal of the project [hyper] is to create a beautiful and
> extensible experience for command-line interface users, built on open
> web standards

Extensions ([hyper_plugins](https://hyper.is/plugins)) are available on npm, a very tangible example is [hyperpower](https://hyper.is/store/hyperpower) (see image below).

[image: Extension for Hyper that turns on power mode, with bonus wow mode]